# App Need to Be Updated. The developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of iOS. iOS15&Xcode12.5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

Now I face a problem when I archive my app and install to my device.
`Environment: Xcode12.5.1 & iOS 15`
It will show this alert to me.
But I don't know what my app should be updated.
Does any good idea to me?
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you added iOS 15 device support platform in Xcode? You need to add iPhoneOSDeviceSupport for iOS 15 in Xcode.

Comment: I add device support already.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things you can check and update:

1. First Go to Xcode and select your Project and then select **Build Settings**
   tab.
2. Select **Build Active Architecture Only** and set as "No",then
3. Select **Excluded Architectures** and type "arm64" only in Any simulator section .

Like this:

[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g89fq.png)

Note: Also check the app target and check Build settings there.